# Exposing a port other than 3000 with Express and Docker

Tags: express, docker, npm, port

I'm using Docker to run an Express app and everything is fine if I run it on port 3000. The Dockerfile I'm using for that is

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

I now wanted to run it on port 3500. I adjusted the Dockerfile to

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3500
CMD ["PORT=3500", "npm", "start" ]
```

and the docker run command to

`docker run -p 3500:3500 me/myapp`

It throws the following error

`container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"PORT=3500\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

I'm sure this is something basic but I'm new to this and couldn't find the solution by googling it. A pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard node port such as 80 or 4000 and map that port to 3500 on the host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to set the environment variable `PORT` as you would in a bash script. Docker doesn't understand that - the `CMD` config wants something which it can execute - a command name & some arguments.

The way to do what you want in Docker is to use `ENV`. In your case, it'd look something like this:

```
ENV PORT 3500
CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

You can put the `ENV` anywhere in the Dockerfile, before the `CMD`, but it makes sense to keep a section of them later, so changes don't force a costly rebuild and more layers can be shared.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that does solve it! I'll mark it correct when I can.